# Screen orientation in tablet

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am using the same code for both tablets and mobile, and I want to write an app for Xlarge screens with landscape. I wrote one condition but when I am rotating into portrait it generates an exception.

I have declared the condition:

```
final boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
```

I want code with if else condition using xlarge and landscape orientations but it should work for only tablets but while coming to mobile it should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to make an application full screen. The [first](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) simply states the application supports a specific dpi. The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: i aggree with your answer but i want with  if else condition using xlarge and lanscape orentations but i should work for only tablets but while comming to mobile it should not work.